# Doesn't a commmon emitter amplifier violate law of conservation of energy?

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Basically voltage and current is gained in an amplifier which ultimately results in power and energy gain? Where does the energy come from? Does it violate law of conservation of energy?

Comment: If amplifiers created energy from nothing, we wouldn't be burning fossil fuels and causing climate change. We could just play music and make all the energy we need.

Answer (score 6):

The energy comes from the power supply. If you have a guitar amplifier and you feed in a few milli-watts from the pick-up, you'll get many tens of watts to the speaker. The extra power came from the power cable that plugs into the mains supply.

If you want to check, try unplugging it.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion might stem from the way operational amplifiers and the like are depicted in schematics - the power supply is often omitted. And there always is a power supply, unless you're dealing with a transformer, which amplifies the current (or the voltage) at the cost of the voltage (or the current), thus keeping the power constant.

[image: The pictogram for an operational amplifier, the vertical leads are for the power supply, they are often omitted.]